# Creating New user in XMPP server using Java

Tags: java, xmpp, webclient, openfire

I am trying to create new user in XMPP using java but i am getting `Null Pointer exception`. can some body help me for this.

I have tried

```
            this.ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new 
            ConnectionConfiguration("Serverip", 5222);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
            connection.login("admin@target.com", "kjbkishan");
            connection.connect();

            AccountManager accountManager = connection.getAccountManager();
            Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
            attributes.put("username", "krishna");
            attributes.put("password", "123456");
            attributes.put("email", "krishna@gmail.com");
            attributes.put("name", "krishnathakkar");

            accountManager.createAccount("krishna@target.local", "123456",attributes);

            Registration registration = new Registration();
            registration.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
            registration.setTo(connection.getServiceName());

            PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketIDFilter(registration.getPacketID()), new PacketTypeFilter(IQ.class));
            PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
            connection.sendPacket(registration);

            connection.connect();
```

any help will be appreciated.

stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:382)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:349)
    at com.verve.XMPPUSer.UserCreating.commectxmpp(UserCreating.java:37)
    at com.verve.XMPPUSer.UserCreating.main(UserCreating.java:27
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace to know which line throws `NPE`

Comment: Now its giving that Not connected to server

Comment: Are you sending the registration packet before connecting and getting error not connected?

Comment: i am connecting it before and then sending it package.. is it right?

Comment: change last two lines - `connect` and then `sendPacket` and it will work :)

Comment: Ya i changed it and still its giving malforexception. :(

Comment: and well i solved it but Changing accountManager.createAccount("krishn123", "123456",attributes);

Comment: @JqueryLearner feel Free to ask bro. Tell me :)

Comment: @Krishna do you have answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952685/property-provider-user-classname-as-specified-in-openfire-xml-differs-from-wha

Comment: @JqueryLearner M trying okey u are configuring openfire in XML is it?

Comment: @Krishna yes,for custom database integration

Comment: @JqueryLearner I have not done this but let me try..

Comment: @Krishna Hope I will get positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here the simple answer.

```
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("ip", 5222);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            connection.connect();
            connection.login("username", "password");
            AccountManager accountManager = connection.getAccountManager();
            accountManager.createAccount("adminCreated1", "123456");
            connection.disconnect();
```

its done.. :D

Comment: i am goint to create new user using above code but its giving error in createAccount. And one more thing when i m going to create account then before it how can i connection.login?

Comment: can u just post your code in some other question and let me see code and connect will be admin and then user will be create/

Comment: @CoronaPintu u can give me link.